# python building tree from list of dicts

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have a list of dicts (dicts are ordered):

```
[
    OrderedDict([('id_1', '1'), ('name_1', 'name_1'), ('id_2', '1'), ('name_2', 'name_1'), ('id_3', '1'), ('name_3', 'name_1'), ('id_4', '1'), ('name_4', '1')]),
    OrderedDict([('id_1', '2'), ('name_1', 'name_2'), ('id_2', '1'), ('name_2', 'name_1'), ('id_3', '1'), ('name_3', 'name_1'), ('id_4', '1'), ('name_4', '1')]),
    ...
    ...
    ...
    OrderedDict([('id_1', 'n'), ('name_1', 'name_n'), ('id_2', 'n'), ('name_2', 'name_n'), ('id_3', 'n'), ('name_3', 'name_n'), ('id_4', 'n'), ('name_4', 'n')])
]
```

I think about it like as table.
so how can i "make a query" to build a tree like:

```
[
    OrderedDict([('id_1', 'n'), ('name_1', 'name_n'), (
        'children', [
            OrderedDict([('id_2', 'name_2'), ('children', [
                OrderedDict([('id_3', 'name_3'), ('children', [])]),
                OrderedDict([('id_6', 'name_6'), ('children', [])]),
                ...
                ...
                OrderedDict([('id_100500', 'name_100500'), ('children', [])]),
            ])]),
            OrderedDict([('id_n', 'name_n'), ('children', [])])
        ])
    ])
]
```

how can i do that with only 1 iteration?

EDITED:

i have an relationship in each dict. i have pairs (id and name) first - parent, then its children, so in the first dict - 4 id's:

- a =  {'id_1': '1', 'name_1': 'name_1'}
- b = {'id_2': '1', 'name_2': 'name_1'}
- c = {'id_3': '1', 'name_3': 'name_1'}
- d = {'id_4': '1', 'name_4': '1'}

so, here:

```
* a - parent
* b - child a
* c - child b
* d - child c
```

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking. are you looking to use each pair of tuples as keys into a dictionary of sorts?

Comment: What is the relationship between the dictionaries in the list and the tree structure you want?  It is not exactly obvious from your question.